# How can I find out what's wrong: IndexError: image index out of range

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I got an error when I'm taking all pixels that I need. What might be wrong here?

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("UIC.bmp")
print(im.size)   # the size is (1200, 800)

pix_list = []


for y in range(0,1201, 80):
    for x in range(0, 801, 80):
        print(x)
        pix = im.load()
        pix_list.append(list(pix[x, y])[2])#here goes error
        print(pix[x, y])



print(pix_list)
decode_list = []
for i in range(len(pix_list)):
    decode_list.append(chr(pix_list[i] - 100))

decode_text = ''.join(decode_list)

print(decode_text)
```

Here is an error:

```
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/projects/BariySatarov/exercise1.2.py", line 27, in <module>
    pix_list.append(list(pix[x, y])[2])
IndexError: image index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

In both loop ranges subtract `1` from final value, size is for example `1200, 800` so indices go from `0` to `1199` and from `0` to `799`.

As you are having it right now they range from `0` to `1200` (out-of-range) and `0` to `800` (out-of-range)

I.e do:

```
for y in range(0,1200, 80):
    for x in range(0, 800, 80):
        # ... rest code
```

The other line:

`pix_list.append(list(pix[x, y])[2])` depends on the format of the image returned by the library so it does'nt seem to have an index at position `2`. I am not aware of the format of the image (how RGB values are returned) but you can check the documentation for that.

Maybe you should use the [method `Image.getdata`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) instead of `Image.load`

One should also make sure the image indeed exists and is found by lib to be loaded and returned.

Comment: tried it, not working. When I coment this two lines 
"pix_list.append(list(pix[x, y])[2])
        print(pix[x, y])"

it starts working ok

Comment: @Nikolas Maybe you should use the [method `Image.getdata`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) instead of `Image.load`

Comment: @Nikolas, one should also make sure the image indeed exists and is found by lib to be loaded

Comment: about  pix_list.append(list(pix[x, y])[2]) : 2 is mean blue color, when I load it in this way, I get [red, green, blue] (in my case I need only blue). I tried to run this code with try/except and it works, but miss some pixels because of the mistakes. However thanks, I'll look for Image.getdata. Maybe it will help